# Detecting if a user is at home

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-location, core-motion, apple-m7

Apple Maps has the ability to route users from home to work from iOS 7 onwards. Is there any method, public or private, which allows detection of wether or not a user is at home?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the "What's new in Core Location" WWDC 2014 video about how to use the `CLVisit` API to detect when a user is at home, work, etc. https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/?id=706

This is only available from iOS 8 and up. So for implementing on iOS 7 there is no Apple api solution.

Comment: This is excellent :) thank you! Can just check wether or not the OS version is greater than 7 and if not just detect basic location and movement to figure out if they're at home or work or not (Best guess solution).

Comment: Definitely! (Sorry I apparently don't know how to use markup in a comment, if you need the swift version I can add something, just let me know!) Using ```respondsToSelector``` checks to make sure it can use the api before you make the call, so this is the method in iOS 8 and up that does the visit tracking.  You can do an else for iOS 7 with your custom roll out solution!

Obj-C:
        ```if ([locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(startMonitoringVisits)]) {
            [locationManager startMonitoringVisits];
            }```

Answer (score -1):

No there is not. You'd need to roll your own custom solution to enable this and get permission from the user to add their home location to your app. As you can imagine, Apple will not allow 3rd party developers to this sort of information without the user's permission.